# Java Appium Android - How to handle sidebar or left panel?

Tags: java, android, cordova, selenium-webdriver, appium

My application which is developed in Cordova. And in automation script, I want to navigate different pages through the sidebar. I am able to locate elements in the sidebar, but don't know why it's not clickable. I tried with locater like id, XPath, accessibility, className, but it's not working.

I tried with coordinates as well, but its x-value in -ve. TouchAction class does not accept -ve value and it's throwing org.openqa.selenium.invalidargumentexception.

ids -
Hamburger Menu - `Id = "SA_hm"`
Services Menu - `Id = "SA_hm_Services"`

I tried -

XPath -

1. `//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']/android.view.View[@resource-id='SA_hm_MyDevices']`
2. `//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']/android.view.View[@index='2']`

Comment: can you show the full code , specially where you are clicking the elements.  Show also  UIautomator viewer screen shot for the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handled this with following logic -

```
Point point = element.getLocation();

int upperY = point.getY();
int lowerY = upperY + element.getSize().getHeight();
int middleY = (upperY + lowerY) / 2;

new TouchAction(((AppiumDriver<MobileElement>) driver)).press(100, middleY).waitAction().release().perform();
```

***please suggest someone have the better approach.***